# Is mongodb realm sdk support to web browsers ..?

Tags: flutter, realm-mobile-platform

Hello everyone I am working on flutter application but in that i am able to use the realm sdk only for desktop and mobile when i am trying to run that application on browser getting errors

i have tryed to run realm sdk run on web but not able to run

Comment: Please share the error you are recieving